# DataGridViews Sorting VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

So i have a problem that i cant seem to overcome. I apply sorting to my Datagrid view as per below. (I can do this manually in the CoulmunHeaderMouseClick event or allow it to be done automatically but for clarity i have included the manual steps)

```
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(_sortedColumnIndex),
_sortedColumnDirection)
```

Now the issue comes in. After editing/adding a row to the DGV the row gets sorted automatically. I want the sorting to be disabled and have it not "snap" into its sorted position.

Is there a way to disable the sorting on the column in the CellEndEdit event, so that the sorting only applies when you click on the Column's Header.

**Example (apply ASC sort on col 2)**

col1 | col2

a | 1

b | 2

c | 3 <<< Edit Column (Change value to 1)

**Result with Auto sort after change**

col1 | col2

a | 1

c | 1

b | 2

**Desired result after editing the cell**

col1 | col2

a | 1

b | 2

c | 1

Changing the sorted column to col1 is not an option.

Comment: Methods i have tried:
Setting the SortMode to NotSortable (`DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable`)

Clearing the sort on the DGV
(`DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(_sortedColumnIndex), Nothing)`)


Tried using different sort modes. I have done programmatic and automatic sorting.

Comment: Here's what I would suggest.  Put your data into a `DataTable` and bind that to your `DataGridView`.  After sorting the grid, you should be able to call `ToTable` on the `DefaultView` of that `DataTable` to get a copy of the original `DataTable` that is in the same order but without a sort aplied.  You can then bind that new `DataTable` to the grid in place of the old and you should see the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this and it basically works.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Sorted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Sorted
    Dim currentTable = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
    Dim newTable = currentTable.DefaultView.ToTable()

    DataGridView1.DataSource = newTable
End Sub
```

It does have some quirks though, both related to the current cell being in the new row when you sort.  I'll try to refine it but I thought that it was worth posting now you or someone else may be able to use it as a basis for a more complete solution in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks, i will give this a bash and let you know if i come right, may need to modify this abit to refresh the original datatable as i use that in other sections of my code.

Comment: Ok so initially it works but i need to update my original dataset wit the new datatable in order to preserve the changed values

Comment: If the `RowState` of each `DataRow` is maintained, which I haven't checked, then you should be able to simply use the final `DataTable` to save changes.  If not, you should be able to call `DataTable.Merge` to merge the final data back into your original `DataTable`.

Comment: Hi, so with a bit of tinkering i got it to work. thank you so much for your help. basically at the end i just replace my original data source with the new data table so that when i save, etc i will still keep my changes. 

the row state was not being maintained as it was a new table. 

`Dim currentTable As DataTable = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
            

Dim newTable As DataTable = currentTable.DefaultView.ToTable()

            DataGridView1.DataSource = newTable
            _originalDataTable = newTable`

Comment: When I mentioned the `RowState` being maintained, I was talking about the `RowState` in the new table being the same as the corresponding row in the old table.  If you're saving the new table then that's exactly what must be happening, which is definitely a good thing in this case.

Comment: So another sub issue that i have so this is that setting the original data table to this new one without the sorting. it detects that the entire table has changed and breaks my save as my saving only saves the changes made to the table.

this had to be done this way as this was designed to be access by multiple users and has locking per cell (kill me now). locking and multi user saving works 100% it is just the sorting that i need to resolve.

with this being said , your answer has been the closest that i have found that will resolve the issue at hand

Comment: I think that `DataTable.Merge` may be able to help.  I'll do some testing and see what I can come up with.